# Indefinite integral of product of CDF and PDF of standard normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Is there a solution to:

$\int ^\infty _x \Phi(z) \phi(z) dz$

where $z$ ~ $N(0,1)$ and $\Phi$ and $\phi$ refer to the CDF and PDF?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\Phi(z)}{\mathrm{d}z}=\phi(z)$$
then, integrating by parts, using $v(z)=\Phi(z)$ and $\mathrm{d}u(z)=\phi(z)$:
$$\int_x^\infty \Phi(z)\phi(z)\ \mathrm{d}z=\left[\Phi(z)^2\right]^\infty_x-\int_x^\infty \phi(z)\Phi(z)\ \mathrm{d}z$$
as $\mathrm{d}v(z)=\phi(z)$, $u(z)=\Phi(z)$, so
$$2\int_x^\infty \Phi(z)\phi(z)\ \mathrm{d}z=\left(1-\Phi(x)^2)\right)$$
as $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}\Phi(z)=1$, so
$$\int_x^\infty \Phi(z)\phi(z)\ \mathrm{d}z=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\Phi(x)^2\right).$$

<s>**Remark.** You could also solve this integral by making a substitution $u(z)=\Phi(z)$, then $\mathrm{d}u=\phi(z)\ \mathrm{d}z$, giving the same answer (check it to see).</s>

Just checked this remark and the limits on the integral don't work, so disregard this.

Comment: *Just checked this remark and the limits on the integral don't work, so disregard this.* Sorry? The substitution works perfectly.

Comment: See my comment below - I had managed to mislabel my limits when I did the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Your Remark was correct. Set $y=\Phi(z)$ then

$$\int_x^\infty \Phi (z)\phi(z) dz =\int_{\Phi (x)}^1 y dy = \frac{1}{2}(1-\Phi(x)^2)$$

Comment: Oops, managed to mislabel my limits when I did the substitution. Thanks for pointing this out!